# How to run a Luigi server against a custom URI

Tags: nginx, tornado, nginx-reverse-proxy, luigi

Can the Luigi server be run against http://localhost:8082/someString ?

[Here](https://community.plotly.com/t/cannot-properly-redirect-nginx-to-dash-application/32964/2) is just one keyword convenient way to do the same in Dash. I was hoping to see a similar way in Luigi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured a way around on my own. First of all, there does not seem to be an external way of doing that. Only way I could do it is by modifying a [this](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/db8ff63f8cd4418be91fa6bfb75b23102a5fae2f/luigi/server.py#L301) line in `luigi/server.py`:

```
299     handlers = [
300         (r'/api/(.*)', RPCHandler, {"scheduler": scheduler}),
301         (r'/someString', RootPathHandler, {'scheduler': scheduler}),
```

Then, `curl -L http://localhost:8082/someString` works fine.

Comment: if you have a compelling reason to change the URL of the server in such a way, you could raise an issue/request with luigi so they implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it out of the box with luigi, because [that's how the server gets started](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/cmdline.py#L12), and there's no options to change the URI path

You may be able to add a proxy in order to achieve this, but then you'll have to
set `--default-scheduler-url=http://localhost:8082/someString` when you start your workers. [See the doc for the configuration](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#core)

Comment: Hi Arthur, thanks for your try. I posted an answer. Let me know what you think. Actually, the proxy problem got me here in the first place. See my other issue https://serverfault.com/questions/1027079/how-to-serve-non-root-static-files-by-nginx